# Solve the system $\begin{cases}2xy=x+xy^2-64\\xy-8=x^2y^2-64x\end{cases}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Solve the system $$\begin{cases}2xy=x+xy^2-64\\xy-8=x^2y^2-64x\end{cases}$$
I've tried everything that has came into my mind and nothing seems to work. Maybe it would be useful to explain how I reached the system.
We are given that three numbers $a,b,c$ are in geometric progression with common ratio in the interval $(-6;6),$ so we can write the numbers as $$a=a, b=aq, c=aq^2, |q|<6.$$ We also know that if we subtract $64$ from the third number, then the 3 numbers become an arithmetic pogression, so $$2aq=a+(aq^2-64).$$
Now if we subtract $8$ from the second term **of the AP**, the 3 numbers become a GP, so $$aq-8=a(aq^2-64).$$ If you put $a=x,q=y,$ you'll get the system I wrote in the beginning of the question, so that's how I got it.

How do I come up with a way to solve it (motivation is important for me!)? For example, I tried to put $xy=x^2y^2-64x+8$ into the first equation and reached $2x^2y^2-128x+16=x+xy^2-64$, which is so useless... Nothing seems to work.

Comment: this is hard to follow.  What are $a,b,c$? How are these numbers related to your problem?  And how do we know that they are in a geometric progression?

Comment: @lulu, just think that we know the numbers $a,b,c$ are in GP with common term in the interval $(-6;6)$.

Comment: I don't understand.  What are $a,b,c$? How are these numbers related to your problem?  And how do we know that they are in a geometric progression?

Comment: @lulu, what do you mean how are they related to my problem? It's literally how I arrived at the system I cannot solve.

Comment: $a,b,c$ do not appear in your problem.  I think you are in the middle of a longer computation and have just handed us pieces of it with insufficient context and explanation.

Comment: @lulu, yep, like the system itself is not enough. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Let $xy=t$. First equation becomes $2t=x+t^2/x-64$, $2xt=x^2+t^2-64x$. Second equation becomes $t^2-t+8=64x$, $x=\frac{t^2-t+8}{64}$. Put this $x$ into first equation and you will get algebraic equation of 4th order. $t=-7$ is one of its roots.

Comment: Shouldn't be the LHS of $aq-8=a(aq^2-64)$ squared?

Comment: Hint: Try multiplying equation 1 with $x$ and subtract is from the second equation. Then use the remaining equation to solve for $x$ in terms of $y$

Answer (score 1):

I think your second equation should be $$\frac{aq-8}{a}=\frac{aq^2-64}{aq-8} \implies (aq-8)^2=a(aq^2-64)$$ Thus,
$$16aq=64+64a \implies q=\frac{4+4a}{a}$$ Plugging this back into $$2aq=a+(aq^2-64)$$ we get $$2a(4a+4)=a^2+(4a+4)^2-64a$$ which produces $a=\frac{4}{9}, a=4$ and $q=10, q=5$ respectively. Eliminating $q=10$ gives us $a=4, b=20, c=100$

Answer (score 0):

The system is $$\begin{cases}2xy=x+xy^2-64\space\space \cdots\cdots(1)\\xy-8=x^2y^2-64x\cdots\cdots(2)\end{cases}$$
equation $(1)$ gives $$x=\dfrac{64}{(y-1)^2}\cdots\cdots(3)$$ in which is easily seen that $(x,y)=(1,-7)$ is an integer solution and it is verify that it is also solution of equation $(2)$.

From $(3)$ in $(2)$ we get
$$y^4-12y^3+22y^2+1012y-511=(y+7)(y^3-19y^2+155y-73)=0$$ The solutions of the cubic are $y_1\approx 0.50091$ and $y_{2,3}\approx9.2495\pm7.7575i$.

Finally the four solutions (only two of them are real) of the system are
$$\boxed{(x,y)=(1,-7),\left(\frac{64}{(y_1-1)^2},y_1\right),\left(\frac{64}{(y_2-1)^2},y_2\right),\left(\frac{64}{(y_3-1)^2},y_3\right)}$$